# Changing Alpha on UITableview background makes interesting transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an app that contains a UITableview.  I selected a color for the background using IB.  Later, I changed the alpha of that background because it looked better.  However, when I now transition to that UITableview it seems to transition in twice. Once with the correct color and alpha, and once with the color without the alpha. I have included a [link](https://youtu.be/qrlKWwBeH2w) to a video of what I am talking about.

I thought perhaps I had done something wrong so I made a sample project.  Just a simple UITableview on the second view controller (TableviewController).  If I do not adjust the alpha it transitions correctly.  But as soon as I change the alpha, it's transition is not correct.  I have done nothing in code for this, but was wondering if I was doing something incorrectly, or if someone else has come across this problem.

The first part of the video is the sample app I made, and the second part is my actual app.

Comment: Can you up your video again, it's not letting us see :/

Comment: @JohnnyRockex, sorry about that, I just made the video public.